# Does the IN PartiQL operator query or scan DynamoDB tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

We need to query a large (2TB+) DynamoDB table to get multiple items based on their partition keys.

We are planning to use PartiQL as it supports the `IN` operator as such:

`SELECT * FROM table_test where pk IN ('1234','1112');`

Would this query do DynamoDB query operations or DynamoDB scan operations under the hood?

We would like to avoid table scans due to them being more expensive.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but still good to know: you can block PartiQL statements that result in a scan at the IAM level ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-iam.html)). It's a good safeguard against regressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would this query do DynamoDB query operations or DynamoDB scan operations under the hood?

It will be doing multiple DynamoDB **queries** as your `WHERE` clause condition statement is filtering on a DynamoDB **partition key**.

This is confirmed as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html#ql-reference.select.parameters):

> To ensure that a SELECT statement does **not result in a full table scan**, the WHERE clause condition must specify a **partition key**. Use the equality or IN operator.

Comment: Does it perform similar with a query on global secondary index?